# ImportError from Twilio.rest

Tags: python, twilio

I have this line in my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
```

But the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_sms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import Client
  File "/Users/utilisateur/Downloads/twilio-6.17.0/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient
  File "/Users/utilisateur/Downloads/twilio-6.17.0/twilio/http/http_client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import Request, Session, hooks
ImportError: No module named requests
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your environment is does not appear to have the `requests` library installed. Run `pip install requests` either from inside the environment in which this script is running (if you're not already, you should consider using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or something similar for this to avoid having to install Python packages globally as root).

Note that this likely wouldn't happen if you'd installed the Twilio library via pip, so I'm guessing you simply downloaded it and attempted to run it. If a Python library is in PyPi (which [twilio is](https://pypi.org/project/twilio/)), you can install it via pip and have its dependencies automatically installed as well.